# How to make a single rowname bold using htmlTable

Tags: r, bold

I made a table using htmlTable, but I would like to make only the first and the seventh rowname bold. How can I do this???

`htmlTable(tabela_classificação_economica', cgroup = c("Mesal","Trimestral", ""),n.cgroup = c(3,3,1))`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smDhZ.png)

Comment: You should post a reproducible example.  What package does `htmlTable` come from?  Add `library( <that package> )` to your code.  Don't use a dataset that's only on your computer, write your example using fake data so we can run it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some other structure that makes sense, i.e. rowgroups, tablepsanners you need to use the css.cell argument, just add a matrix with strings that corresponds to your size and decorate with whatever you need:

```
mx <- paste("value ", 1:6) %>% matrix(ncol = 3)
colnames(mx) <- c("A", "B", "C") %>%  paste("header", .)
rownames(mx) <- letters[1:2]

css.cell <- matrix("", ncol = 4, nrow = 3)
css.cell[2,1] <- "text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold" # <-- the magic
mx %>%
  addHtmlTableStyle(spacer.celltype = "skip",
                    css.cell = css.cell) %>% 
  htmlTable()
```